# how to securely delete a file from ufs device in linux

Tags: linux, scsi

Assuming I have some files stored on a ufs storage chip and I mounted it on linux. Is there any possible way to securely delete these file?

Comment: Possibly answered in https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62555/how-do-i-securely-erase-usb-flash-drives

Comment: @mtak Be aware that your link comment will wipe whole drive but thanks to Over-provisioning and Wear leveling the data can still be on disk hardly to detect but still there.

Comment: no, that's just for ssd and usb device and they can be erased offline. But for me actually I want to do it online, which means there is still an operating system running on it while doing the erasing.  Obviously you can't rewrite the whole device with random number. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The way how lot flash memory (and ssd) works is that they try to redirect writes to be equal over whole device so overwriting don't really overwrite the same blocks.

EDIT [REF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) [REF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification#Over-provisioning)